# wpa_supplicant says network is disabled

Tags: networking, gentoo, wpa-supplicant, wpa, wpa2-eap

When trying to connect to a network (specifically a WPA2 enterprise network for a university) with `wpa_supplicant` on Gentoo Linux, the network is shown as disabled when the flag is not set.

My `wpa_supplicant.conf` :

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
    ssid="TheNetwork"
    eap=PEAP
    identity="redacted"
    password="redacted"
    ca_cert="/etc/ssl/certs/AddTrust_External_Root.pem"
    ca_path="/etc/ssl/certs/"
    phase1="peapver=0"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}

network={
    ssid="Another network that works"
    key_mgmt=NONE
    disabled=1 # This is obviously not normally disabled
}

network={
    ssid="Yet another working network"
    psk="redacted"
    disabled=1 # Likewise
}
```

Output of `sudo wpa_supplicant -iwlp3s0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -d`, with repetitive lines removed:

```
wpa_supplicant v2.6
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Initializing interface 'wlp3s0' conf '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf' driver 'default' ctrl_interface 'N/A' bridge 'N/A'
Configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf' -> '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'
Reading configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'
ctrl_interface='/var/run/wpa_supplicant'
    Priority group 0
   id=0 ssid='TheNetwork'
   id=1 ssid='Another network that works'
   id=2 ssid='Yet another working network'
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
...
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:9
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Driver-advertised extended capabilities (default) - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40
nl80211: Driver-advertised extended capabilities mask (default) - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40
nl80211: interface wlp3s0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 4 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with non-AP handle 0x55701974e5f0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55701974e5f0 match=0104
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55701974e5f0 match=040a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55701974e5f0 match=040b
...
rfkill: initial event: idx=1 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=4 linkmode=1 (userspace-control), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
Add interface wlp3s0 to a new radio phy0
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=US (DFS-FCC)
nl80211: 2402-2472 @ 40 MHz 30 mBm
nl80211: 5170-5250 @ 80 MHz 23 mBm
nl80211: 5250-5330 @ 80 MHz 23 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5490-5730 @ 160 MHz 23 mBm (DFS)
nl80211: 5735-5835 @ 80 MHz 30 mBm
nl80211: 57240-63720 @ 2160 MHz 40 mBm
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
wlp3s0: Own MAC address: [redacted]
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=4 (wlp3s0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
...
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=4 (wlp3s0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=5 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wlp3s0: RSN: flushing PMKID list in the driver
nl80211: Flush PMKIDs
wlp3s0: No enabled networks (3 disabled networks)
wlp3s0: State: DISCONNECTED -> INACTIVE
ENGINE: Loading dynamic engine
ENGINE: Loading dynamic engine
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
nl80211: Skip set_supp_port(unauthorized) while not associated
EAPOL: KEY_RX entering state NO_KEY_RECEIVE
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED
Using existing control interface directory.
ctrl_iface bind(PF_UNIX) failed: Address already in use
ctrl_iface exists, but does not allow connections - assuming it was leftover from forced program termination
Successfully replaced leftover ctrl_iface socket '/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlp3s0'
wlp3s0: Added interface wlp3s0
wlp3s0: State: INACTIVE -> DISCONNECTED
nl80211: Set wlp3s0 operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=4 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
random: Got 20/20 bytes from /dev/random
EAPOL: disable timer tick
```

What sticks out to me is the line `wlp3s0: No enabled networks (3 disabled networks)`. This appears despite the fact that there are clearly only two disabled networks.  Further evidence that the first network is being disabled despite the lack of a `disabled=1` flag is that when running the wpa_supplement command with the other two networks *enabled*, a scan is performed and output, but all relevant APs are skipped as "disabled", "SSID mismatch", and "SSID mismatch", even though the SSIDs clearly do match. When running wpa_supplicant with the other two networks removed, the line `wlp3s0: No enabled networks (1 disabled networks)` appears.

What in the configuration is causing this to occur?

Comment: Does the number of disabled networks increase if you add another network to your `wpa_supplicant.conf`?

Comment: Hmm, I have tried reading the source and guessing why it might think the network is disabled. It looks like it might treat any `key_mgmt=WPA-PSK` as disabled if there is no `psk` set for it. It seems that the default `key_mgmt` would be `WPA-PSK`. Have you tried `key_mgmt=WPA-EAP`?

Comment: @binki No, any other networks I add are enabled and usable.

I did add `key_mgmt=WPA-EAP` to to the network in question, and I was able to connect. I guess it was much simpler than I thought. Though it would be nice if more information was given in that case. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for reporting back—I can not easily access a system which I can use to test this and, furthermore, I don’t even know of a PEAP network I could use for testing if I did. I went ahead and made that into an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a `network` block in `wpa_supplicant.conf`, the default value for `key_mgmt` is `WPA-PSK IEEE8021X` ([`config.c` sets to `DEFAULT_KEY_MGMT`](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/wpa_supplicant/config.c?h=hostap_2_6#n2496), [definition of `DEFAULT_KEY_MGMT`](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/wpa_supplicant/config_ssid.h?h=hostap_2_6#n21)). Later on, when checking if a network is “disabled”, one of the checks is for whether the block [has `key_mgmt=WPA-PSK` but does **not** have `psk=` set](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.c?h=hostap_2_6#n5945).

Thus, there are two issues with your network block.

1. `wpa_supplicant` will not even attempt to do PEAP authentication because you do not have `key_mgmt=WPA-EAP`. I was unable to test this myself, but you mentioned that setting this helped in the comments.
2. Since you are using the default value `key_mgmt=WPA-PSK IEEE8021X`, your block will be considered disabled because you have not set `psk`. Obviously, this second issue is not really something you care about because you intend to use PEAP ;-).

Based on `wpa_supplicant-2.6`.